# Parse LESS using Ruby

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra, less

I'm pretty new to ruby, but I'm even less familiar with LESS. Please, if you could, explain this as plain and simple as possible, because neither the documentation nor scattered blog entries have helped me in any way.

I'm using `sinatra` and I've got a file named `main.less` in my `views` folder. In my `layout.haml` a non-existent `main.css` is referenced. More exactly: `/stylesheets/main.css`. So I want to parse `main.less` using the less gem. I think I need to do something like this:

```
get '/stylesheets/main.css' do
  less ...
end
```

But I really can't figure out the exact code. Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the `less` gem installed, it would look like this:

```
get '/stylesheets/main.css' do
  less :main
end
```

By default this would look for `main.less` in your `views/` directory under the directory you are running sinatra in. So, it's looking for `views/main.less`.

You can of course configure sinatra to load templates from elsewhere.

You can also configure sinatra with a very rails-like asset pipeline via the `sinatra-asset-pipeline` gem. Then your stylesheets would live in `assets/` by default. I have a [skeleton sinatra app here](https://github.com/carlzulauf/skeletra) which shows `sinatra-asset-pipeline` in action.